# In Android Studio 4.1 I cannot see gradle under the Tool Windows

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to put gradle in offline mode as it is taking way too long to do its job. Now from what I read online it is supposed to be under View->Tool Windows  the there should be a gradle there for me to click so I can toggle it to offline however I do not have the gradle link on my Menu. I also tried via Settings->Build,Execution and Deployment->Gradle but to no avail. [gradle settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh1Qd.png)

I was now considering editing the gradle files themselves however I'm not too keen as I don't know what the cost of that will be since I dont really know how this machine works under the bonnet.

Anyone with knowledge please assist, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing Gradle settings from the sidebar to the right of the window and find 'Toggle Offline Mode'

[Toggle Offline Mode - Gradle Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGEsE.png)

Comment: HI Farjad thank you for your answer.. On my IDE there is no such thing on the right side